# Logging unhandled exceptions in Spring Mvc Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I want to capture the exceptions throughout the whole application and save them to my database. I am having difficulty choosing what approach to use. I know I want the exceptions to be handled globally. I am refering to this source :https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc and I have my @controlleradvice but the exceptions do not come throught it at all. Could anyone provide me with a specific example of how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: " I know I want the exceptions to be handled globally " , Not a good Idea, you should not handle the exceptions globally, I believe you meant to say you wanted to capture the exception traces and log them into DB

Comment: I suggest using Logback and a database appender, this gives you that out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ControllerAdvice` and `ExceptionHandler` annotations together to capture specific exceptions and do whatever you want with them. As @M. Deinum said, for exception logging, you can achieve the same result by using logback or log4j `Database Appender`s but still it's a good idea to capture exceptions in `Service Layer` and translate them to more appropriate say `Status Code`s, like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
public class GenericServiceExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity handleUncaughtException(Exception ex) {
        return badRequest(ex.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

This exception handler, catch all `Exception` exceptions thrown by beans that annotated by `RestController` and turn them to a `400 Bad Request` response.